# Does everything in my code look good?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Anything I could improve on?? I am a python beginner. Is there anything I could do to make my code look cleaner or just make it look more professional? Thanks

```
while True:
    print('What password will you be storing?')
    PassChoice = input()
    print('What is your username or email for this account?')
    UserOrEmail = input()
    print("What is the password for " + str(PassChoice) + '?')
    Password = input()
    print('Your password for ' + str(PassChoice) + ' has been stored.')
    WebsiteAndPassword = (str(PassChoice) + '| ' + str(UserOrEmail) +': ' + 
str(Password) + '\n')
    break

PasswordFile = open('importantpasswords.txt', 'a')
PasswordFile.write(str(WebsiteAndPassword))
PasswordFile.close()
```

Comment: For questions about working code go to https://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Some obviousthings: adhere to community-accepted standards (PEP-8 for example) and don't store passwords in a plain text file ;)

Comment: Voting to close question as opinion based

Comment: I would say more like too broad, this not about opinions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I would use the getpass https://docs.python.org/3/library/getpass.html library when getting a users password and also you could have simplified it by doing:

```
passChoice = input("What password will you be storing?")
```

or with getpass:

```
import getpass

getpass.getpass(prompt="What password will you be storing?")
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that this site is not for code review, but since you're new there is something that is really obvious:

```
    PassChoice = input('What password will you be storing?')
    UserOrEmail = input('What is your username or email for this account?')
    Password = input('What is the password for ' + PassChoice + '?')
```

When you want to ask the user for an input, you can give your string as a parameter to the input function. Also, you don't have to cast `PassChoice` to string since it is the type that `input()` returns.

Comment: You should avoid giving "passwords" in plaintext input fields anyway

Comment: Yes, that is for sure, he was asking on how to improve his code. I hope this is for educational purposes. Storing real passwords in text files would be silly.

Comment: Thank you all for the useful info. I was also thinking it was stupid, but I just don't know any other way of doing it. Any ideas?